# I can set images to right side using align right, but not with floats?

Tags: css

```
#sponsors { 
  float: right; 
  display: inline; 
  width: 728px; 
  height: 100px; 
  margin: 60px 11px 0;
}

<div id="sponsors">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/sponsors/1.png"></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/sponsors/2.png"></a>
</div>
```

I can't move images to the right side of div with this, but **div align="right"** works.

How can I set images to right side using css3?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `display` to `block` and add `text-align:right`

```
#sponsors { 
  float: right; 
  display: block; /* or remove this line, as block is default for div */
  width: 728px; 
  height: 100px; 
  margin: 60px 11px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Display `inline` doesn't make much sense on elements with a `width` and a `height` sepcified. I assume you want the browser to respect your `width` and `height` so `display` should be `block`, or be removed completely as it is a `div` element which implies `display:block` by default. Then you want the elements inside the div to align to the right, which you do by applying `text-align`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#sponsors a img {
  float:right;
}
```

Currently you are floating the sponsors div to the right, instead of the images inside the sponsors div. Target the images to float them, and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The images themselves need to be floated or their parent element needs to have its text alignment modified.

Floated: http://jsfiddle.net/MAz4Q/1/

```
#sponsors { 
  width: 728px; 
  height: 100px; 
  margin: 60px 11px 0;
}

#sponsors img {
    float: right;
}
```

Aligned: http://jsfiddle.net/MAz4Q/2/

```
#sponsors { 
  width: 728px; 
  height: 100px; 
  margin: 60px 11px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```